# (whonix) Arm shows external ip or loopback address?

Tags: whonix

About whonix gateway,arm(page 2/5) sometimes(not always) shows 127.0.0.1 as my ip from the top to the bottom,like

127.0.0.1        -->  nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn(us)
127.0.0.1        -->  nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn(de)

But a few month ago, arm(page 2/5) always showed my external address,instead of 127.0.0.1.
Actually,I'm using (and was using a few month ago)vpn with whonix(vpn before whonix) and external ip was vpn's ip,like

999.999.999.999(vpn's ip)    --> nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn(us)
999.999.999.999(vpn's ip)    --> nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn(de)

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

This seems to have changed with Whonix 13, according to this: https://phabricator.whonix.org/T434

Have a nice day,

Ego